# Category name in dataflow

Tags: magento-1.9, export

I am exporting my products for a Google Shopping feed and i need to get the category names in the CSV file. Is there any way to do this with dataflow profiles?

Magento 1.9

Comment: is it solve your issue?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet

Comment: solution   :  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59355/custom